# JSON PHP encoding issue

Tags: php, json, encoding

I trying write a simple php script witch get a string and return string in json.

All database and forms and html was set according to this article.
http://kunststube.net/frontback/

And it  works great:

1. The form send string to php with a text writen in
   russian/japanese/whatever,
2. Then it find the similar string in the database.

BUT. When i print this string with JSON:

```
$data = array('success'=> true,'message'=>$row['phrase']);
echo json_encode($data);
```

It returns to me something like this `{"success":true,"message":"\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e \u0441\u0442\u043e\u0438\u0442"}`

When i print

```
echo $row['phrase'];
```

it returns normal string in russian/japanese/whatever

Any suggestions?

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\ UPDATE \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have a field

When the field is changes this function execute

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mike').bind('webkitspeechchange',function()
    {

        a= $(this).val();
        recognizeAjax(a);

})  ;
});


function recognizeAjax(string) {

    var postData ="string="+string;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        data: postData,
        beforeSend: function(x) {
            if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            }
        },
        url: 'restURL.php',
        success: function(data) {
            // 'data' is a JSON object which we can access directly.
            // Evaluate the data.success member and do something appropriate...
            if (data.success == true){
                alert(data.message);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.message+'11111');
            }
        }
    });


}
```

And here is my php

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
// Here's the argument from the client.
$string = $_POST['string'];
$quest=1;
//$quest=$_POST['quest'];
//$event=$_POST['event'];
//$success = processDomain($string);

//!!!!!!!!!!!!! PLEASE SAY NOTHING ABOUT THE WAY I CONNECT it doesn't metter right now!!!! 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "*******", "*****") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("vocabulary", $con) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);


$sql="SELECT * FROM `0` WHERE event_name = 'taxi' AND quest_id = '".$quest."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{


    if ($string == htmlspecialchars($row['phrase']))
    {
       // $sql="SELECT * FROM `1` WHERE step_id = '".$row['step_id']."' AND quest_id = '".$quest."'";

       // $result = mysql_query($sql);
       // $answer = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        // Set up associative array

 $data = array('success'=> true,'message'=>$row['phrase']);
//echo $row['phrase'];
// JSON encode and send back to the server
echo json_encode($data);
        break;
    } else {
// Set up associative array
         $data = array('success'=> false,'message'=>'aint no sunshine');
         echo json_encode($data);
        break;
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
```

But i always receive undefied11111 alert (according to javascript)

So i made new field

```
<form  method="post" id="wer" action="restURL.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input name="www" style="position: relative;"  lang="ru" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And it returns me {"success":true,"message":"\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e \u0441\u0442\u043e\u0438\u0442"} When the string is fit.

Comment: That's how Unicode characters are represented in JSON.

Comment: So how can i see it in normal charecters?

Comment: i have this in my php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: It should be `header('Content-type: application/json');`. There's no `charset` option for JSON, the encoding has to follow the JSON specification. `JSON.parse()` in the browser will decode the characters properly.

Comment: What is the problem? Please give us some context WHY your question raises an issue.

Comment: Actually i do exactly the same thing like in here
http://www.islandsmooth.com/2010/04/send-and-receive-json-data-using-ajax-jquery-and-php/

Wait a minute i will update my question

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, `\uXXXX` is a way of encoding unicode characters so the resulting string is ASCII safe.

For example `\u0441` is just the cyrillic small letter es. Strictly speaking you shouldn't need to encode these characters, but it's probably safer that way.